# Repository for GPS tracklog (better gpx format)

Tags: gpx, trajectory

I've developed some algorithms that work with GPS trajectories. So I need a repository in which I can download GPS trajecotries to run my test.

I most need marine and air tajectories, better if fileformat was a .gpx.

Comment: Have you read the similar discussion here?   http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5858/need-a-benchmark-gps-trajectory-data-set-anyone

Comment: Yes, but I haven't found no marine/air trajectories.

Answer (score 4):

GPS track logs for vessels can be accessed using [AIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Identification_System).

Ships broadcast information such as GPS position, heading, and speed.  Updates are sent over radio at periods of between [2 and 30 secs](http://web.arundale.co.uk/docs/ais/ais_reporting_rates.html) for a moving ship.

Data can be accessed on sites such as [aprs.fi](http://aprs.fi/?call=i%2F265285000&_s=mv) who provide an api, although not in GPX format.  Many commercial sources also exist that can provide historic data.

[image]

Comment: marinetraffic.com is a similar service.

Answer (score 0):

You can get cycling activities from [Strava](http://www.strava.com) in JSON format using this url:

```
http://www.strava.com/activities/[activityID]/streams
```

Activities and users are freely browseable.